# RegEx: Delete invalid characters in a variable-name

Tags: regex, character

let's assume I have this variable name:
**$$5**Var**#**_**#**Name**#**1**!!**

Now I want to delete the invalid characters (in bold). The rules are:
Allowed characters are a-z, A-Z, underline and 0-9 but (here it comes) not as first character.
(Expected result: Var_Name1)

I'm currently do this in 2 steps:
`s/[^a-zA-Z_]//g` and than `s/^[0-9]//g`

Is it possible to do this with one RegEx?

Thanks und greetings

Comment: any particular language?

Comment: And on what input are you going to do these replacements? On source code? If that is the case, you should watch out that you don't replace illegal characters that are in string literals or comments, for example.

Comment: @aioobe, based on the syntax `s///` I'd guess this is perl

Comment: In "real" i will use the TR1 extension of the microsoft c++ compiler (part of Visual Studio 2008 SP1).
I just used the perl syntax for simplification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
s/^[^a-zA-Z_]+|[^a-zA-Z_0-9]+//g
```

Here the `g` at the end indicates a global replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Your current method removes all digits in the first step, so the second step is pointless, and the result would be `Var_Name` rather than the expected `Var_Name1`.

You can use a pattern like this to match what to remove:

```
^[^A-Za-z_]+|\W+
```

Example in C#:

```
string name = "$$5Var#_#Name#1!!";
name = Regex.Replace(name, @"^[^A-Za-z_]+|\W+", String.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Output:

```
Var_Name1
```

Comment: actually, his first step only removes the *first* digit. (or more correctly, non-letter or _ ). note the lack of the 'g' switch

Comment: @jb: In that case each step would not remove more than one character, so using the current method on the example would give `$5Var#_#Name#1!!`, not even close to the expected result...